# Jquery: find and replace text is not working

Tags: jquery

I want to change the text of h2

```
<div id="freeads_box" class="freeads_box">
  <input value="3" type="radio" name="radioname">
  <h2>sometest </h2>
</div>
```

I tried

```
var x=4;
$("#freeads_box").find("input[value='3']").next("h2").html(x);
$("#freeads_box").find("input[value='3']").siblings("h2").html(y);
$("#freeads_box").children("input[value='3']").end().children("h2").html(x);
```

But nothing seems to change the text in h2

### update

```
var s=$(".freeads_box").find("input[value='3']").val();
alert(s);
```

prints undefined

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have wrong id in selector probably, $("#freeads_box") would be $("#free_box")

Comment: can you check this fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/1634/) , hope it may help you.

Comment: do you have only one div id="freeads_box" ?

Comment: no it has somany div id="freeads_box it's already written code I am just changing part of it

Comment: @Adil I changed it still not working

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan, check if you have successfully added jQuery and you do not have error on your page as this is working for me, http://jsbin.com/patuyexuzu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

This seems working :

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var x = 4;
  $("#free_box").find("input[value='3']").next("h2").html(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="free_box">
  <input value="3" type="radio" name="radioname">
  <h2>sometest </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the js code by

```
var x=4;
$("#free_box").find("input[value='3']").next("h2").html(x);
$("#free_box").find("input[value='3']").siblings("h2").html(y);
$("#free_box").children("input[value='3']").end().chilren("h2").html(x);
```

Hope it may help you...

Comment: Id you are using is html code and jquery are quite different. I changed to same id...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have many `<div id="freeads_box">` use `<div class="freeads_box">`

replace id by **class** and in your jquery :

```
$(".freeads_box").find("input[value='3']").next("h2").html(x);
```

You can only have one **id unique** by page.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var x = "changed !";
  $(".freeads_box").find("input[value='3']").next("h2").html(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="freeads_box">
  <input value="3" type="radio" name="radioname">
  <h2>sometest </h2>
</div>
<div class="freeads_box">
  <input value="1" type="radio" name="radioname">
  <h2>sometest </h2>
</div>
<div class="freeads_box">
  <input value="3" type="radio" name="radioname">
  <h2>sometest </h2>
</div>
<div class="freeads_box">
  <input value="4" type="radio" name="radioname">
  <h2>sometest </h2>
</div>
```